# Acceder a variable local de express desde otro archivo js

Tags: javascript, nodejs, express

Tengo definido `user` como variable de sesión. Quiero que dicha variable este disponible en un archivo que contiene los helpers de  handlebars, esto con el fin de evaluar si la propiedad `user.rol`, es igual a "Administrador", entonces devolver a la vista el botón eliminar

archivo principal de la aplicación **app.js**

```
app.use((req, res, next) => {
  app.locals.user = req.user;
  next();
})
```

helpers de handlebars **helpers.js**

```
    module.exports = {

    rol: () => {
        let btnEliminar = `<button>Eliminar</button>`;
        if (app.locals.user.rol == 'Administrador') {
            return btnEliminar
        }
    }
}
```

Desde la vista `index.hbs`estoy llamando el helper de la siguiente forma 
`{{#rol}}{{/rol}}`

El codigo actual no funciona obtengo el siguiente error `/node/sicne/views/configuracion/rol/index.hbs: app is not defined`

Comment: ¿Hay algún problema si le pasas la variable como parámetro a tu función: `rol: (userRol) => {...}`?

Comment: Si puedo pasarle normalmente pero la cuestión es que necesito mostrar el botón dentro de las filas generadas dinámicamente por un each de la siguiente forma `{{#each row}}
                        <tr>                            
                            <td>
                                {{#rol user.rol }}{{/rol}}
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        {{/each}}`  y al insertar `{{#rol user.rol }}{{/rol}}` dentro del each ya no funciona, y si hago un `console.log` en el archivo helper.js obtengo una variable indefinida.

Comment: ¿Y estás seguro que `req.user` contiene datos?

Comment: Es que lo he probado y a mi me va de maravillas, lo único que se me ocurre es que `req.user` sea `undefined`

Comment: lo que me dices si funciona `{{#rol user.rol}}{{/rol}}` y me devuelve el botón, pero al colocarlo dentro del `each` ya no funciona, no entiendo. Por esta razón quería capturar en el `helpers.js` la información del usuario.

Comment: dentro del `{{#each row}}` ya no puedo imprimir `{{user.rol}} `

Comment: ya lo resolví  y tiene que ver en el ambito de la variable. hay que indicar que la variable esta fuera del each de la siguiente forma `{{#rol ../user.rol}}{{/rol}}`